# Apache Beam -BigQueryIO using Apex runner

Tags: apex, apache-beam

Writing data into table in Apache beam using apex/spark runner. However facing exception while running the program using apex runner.

```
 List<TableFieldSchema> fields = new ArrayList<>();
            fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("Id").setType("STRING"));
            fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("row").setType("STRING"));
            TableSchema schema = new TableSchema().setFields(fields);

PCollection<TableRow> data= pipeline.apply("ReadLines", TextIO.read().from(inputDir + "data.txt"))
        .apply(ParDo.of(new ExtractDataFn()));

data.apply(BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                 .to("my-project:output.output_table")
                 .withSchema(schema)
                 .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
                 .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_EEDED));

static class ExtractDataFn extends DoFn<String, TableRow> {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {

        if (c.element() != null) {
            TableRow row = new TableRow().set("Id", c.element().substring(1, 5)).set("row", c.element());
            c.output(row);
        }
    }
}
```

After executing above program using command  *mvn compile exec:java ... --runner=ApexRunner" -Papex-runner*, getting below exception:

```
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO$Write.expand(BigQueryIO.java:1398)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO$Write.expand(BigQueryIO.java:974)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:525)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:460)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:284)
```

Could you please guide me what would be the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error due to your program (including the Beam SDK) and the Apex runtime environment both including Guava, apparently at conflicting versions. The typical answer is that you should either change your Guava dependency version if possible, or shade it in Maven.

For more detailed instructions on how to handle each of these, search for "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions".